# R - Replace items in a list based on another vector

Tags: r, list, replace

I am doing a fuzzy name matching exercise and am trying to reduce the number of spelling variations of the same name using tidystringdist. I end up with a dataframe of matches containing two vectors. One has the original value and the second has the value it needs to be changed into. So I need to go back to the original vector of names and change them based on the df with the match values. Normal this would be easy, left_join() on the original names and done. But, my original names can have anywhere from 1 to 4 values in it (multiple owners on properties) so the values to be changed are actually a list of lists.  Here is a reprex of what I have done so far:

```
library(dplyr)

data_to_change <- data.frame(house_number = c(1,2,3),
                             animal = rbind(c("dog|cat|monkey"), 
                                            c("goldfish"), 
                                            c("mouse|dog|rabbit|squirrel"))) %>% 
  mutate(animal_split = strsplit(animal, "[|]"))

new_names <- data.frame(cbind(V1 = c("dog", "rabbit"),
                              V2 = c("doggy", "bunny")))
```

The original data looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "dog"    "cat"    "monkey"

[[2]]
[1] "goldfish"

[[3]]
[1] "mouse"    "dog"      "rabbit"   "squirrel"
```

And I would like to change the animal names so the result looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "doggy"  "cat"    "monkey"

[[2]]
[1] "goldfish"

[[3]]
[1] "mouse"    "doggy"    "bunny"    "squirrel"
```

I don't believe I can simply use replace, because the target and match df list are of different lengths. And I don't think I can unlist it and change it because I need to preserve the association with the house number and other animals in the house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `lapply()` to wrap around your list, and use `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed()` to replace the text.

```
library(stringi)

data_to_change$animal_split <- lapply(data_to_change$animal_split, stri_replace_all_fixed, new_names$V1, new_names$V2, vectorize = F)

data_to_change$animal_split
[[1]]
[1] "doggy"  "cat"    "monkey"

[[2]]
[1] "goldfish"

[[3]]
[1] "mouse"    "doggy"    "bunny"    "squirrel"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I got a solution from a friend that worked, but was more complicated and took an hour to run on a 700k+ row dataset. This took less than a minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As these are fixed matches, we can use `deframe` to convert the data.frame into a named vector and then use that to match and replace the vector elements in the `list` by looping over (`map`) and finally `coalesce` with the original vector so that the NAs are replaced by original vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
data_to_change %>%
  mutate(animal_split = map(animal_split,
      ~ coalesce(deframe(new_names)[.x], .x)))
```

-output

```
  house_number                    animal                  animal_split
1            1            dog|cat|monkey            doggy, cat, monkey
2            2                  goldfish                      goldfish
3            3 mouse|dog|rabbit|squirrel mouse, doggy, bunny, squirrel
```

Comment: This worked kinda... in the DF, the data was stored as "c(`NA` = "mouse", dog = "doggy", rabbit = "bunny", `NA` = "squirrel"). Could probably wrangle this into the right format, but the next solution worked so well, I didn't bother to try.

Comment: @BobSomeAle that is a named vector you showed.  In my code, that was created with `deframe(new_names)` so if your named vector is `new_names`, you just remove the `deframe`